# Modify just one jumbotron background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two jumbotron in my page, its html:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 class="display-5">TEST</h3>
```

and I want to change the color of just one, but when I edit its css both changes.

```
.jumbotron-fluid{
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

I tried to put an id and change the background using it but didn't work.

Comment: Add new class to first jumbotron, like `bg-red`. In css add `.bg-red { background-color: red!important; }`. Or you can use this css selector just for the first one: `.jumbotron:first-child { background-color: red!important; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add I'd to jumbotron there is no reason for it to not work**

```
  #id {
      background-color: red!important;
   }
```

Or  add another class to it

```
  <div class="jumbotron red"></div>
```

Css

```
  .red {
      background-color: red!important;
   }
```

Or use inline style

```
     <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: red"></div>
```